# How can I insert text in front of a text node in DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, title

I want to edit the title of my website with PHP and the DOM library. I have an HTML template that already contains the name of the homepage in the title
template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> – Testsite
    </title>
    <meta name="author" content="Kasagranda" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Visual Studio Code" />
    <meta name="language" content="de" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width =device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3299fc" />
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        Testcontent
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
 $vl = new DomDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$vl->loadHTMLFile("template.html");
$t = $vl->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0(;
$sitetitle = $vl->createTextNode("Experiment");
$hometitle = $t->nodeValue;
$title = $vl->insertBefore($sitetitle, $hometitle);
$vl->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$vl->formatOutput = true;
echo  $vl->saveHTML();
?>
```

The output in the browser now looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="de">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> &ndash; Testsite
     </title>
 <meta name="author" content="Kasagranda">
 <meta name="generator" content="Visual Studio Code">
 <meta name="language" content="de">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width =device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#3299fc">
 </head>
 <body>
     <main>
         Testcontent
 
     </main>
 </body>
 </html>Experiment
```

Why is "Experimentell" not inserted before "test site", but appended to the bottom of the page? Can anybody help me further? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The second argument to `insertBefore()` should be a node, not a string.

Comment: I have now tried to turn the string into a node.
$ hometitle = $ vl-> createTextNode ($ t-> nodeValue);
The result is this message:

Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Not Found Error in /home/webpages/lima-city/kiddi-goggel/kiddi-goggel.lima-city.de/KV-Seite.php:7 Stack trace: # 0 / home / webpages / lima-city / kiddi-goggel / kiddi-koggel.lima-city.de / KV-Seite.php (7): DOMNode-> insertBefore (Object (DOMText), Object (DOMText)) # 1 {main} thrown in / home / webpages / lima-city / kiddi-koggel / kiddi-koggel.lima-city.de / KV-Page.php on line 7

Comment: You have to add `$hometitle` to the DOM before you can insert something before it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `insertBefore`. Why don't you just change the text of the `<title>` node by concatenating strings? `$t->nodeValue = "Experimental " . $t->nodeValue;`

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that nodeValue can also edit text nodes. I thought you could only read them out.